# How to diagram a repeating set of steps from multiple paths in Visio?

Tags: visio

[image]

Is there a proper way to diagram this? I have two different paths, but at some point in the process Step 1, Step 2 and Step 3 will be done.

It's possible that this flowchart will be very large, and Steps 1 thru 3 will be run thru from many different paths.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there is a *proper* way to document this, but generally if you are repeating the same steps in the same sequence it is a good idea to carve this out as a sub-process or predefined process.

I would recommend coming up with a meaningful name to describe steps 1 - 3 and then replacing those steps in your diagram with a "predefined process" shape with that name.

[image]

Then you would create a supplemental sheet to include your predefined process (or sub-process):

[image]

And your initial sheet would look something like this:

[image]

By simplifying your diagram in this fashion it will also make it easier for your audience to understand.  I hope this helps!